# ASP.Net EditorFor with custom expression

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, editorfor

The built-in EditorFor does only work with member access expressions.

But in one scenario, I need to multiply the value with 100 and have that inside a text box.
That is because the value represents a percentage and the user should be able to input 27 which is internally stored as 0.27.
For this it would be nice to have something like `EditorFor(m => m.MyValue * 100)`.

Is there any equivalent for that?

Comment: IMHO that would not only be very hard to implement, it would also be very wrong. Conversion of input values is not a responsibility of the View layer. Also, maintaining view code on ASP.NET MVC is already hard enough, please avoid placing C# code in there as much as you can.

Answer (score 1):

Just add something like `MyValueAsPercentage` to your view model:

```
public class MyDataModel
{
    public double MyValue { get; set; }
}

// ...

public class MyViewModel
{
    public double MyValueAsPercentage { get; set; }

    public MyViewModel(MyDataModel dataModel)
    {
        this.MyValueAsPercentage = dataModel.MyValue * 100;
    }

    public MyDataModel ToDataModel()
    {
        return new MyDataModel() { MyValue = MyValueAsPercentage / 100 };
    }
}
```

Now you can use the same member access expression over your view model:

```
Html.EditorFor(m => m.MyValueAsPercentage)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is my current approach, but i would like to know if it is possible without a dummy property.

Comment: @wertzui Well, the `ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression` which is used internally, only understands expressions of type "member access", "array index" and "indexer".

Comment: I thought that maybe someone came up with something like EditorForCustomExpression(), like someone already came up with EditorForMany() to implement custom templates with Lists.

Comment: @wertzui Sure, you can make a custom version, but in this case you'd at least need to initialize model metadata "your own way". It seems to me like a little bit of an overhead considering what you're trying to achieve. Personally, I don't see why having a special view model property is a bad approach since the view model is basically a version of your data entry "tuned" for viewing/editing.

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding an attribute to your property

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:P2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public decimal MyValueASPercentage { get; set; }
```

Now a value of 0.27 will appear as 27 % on your page. Hope that helps

Comment: Wow, that looks neat but will `MyValueAsPercentage` have `0.27` when I type `27%` or will it be `27`?

Comment: I need it without the '%'-sign. Additionally I'm looking for a solution without having to modify the model.